# Jquery js-hotkeys plugin adding key pressed into input field

Tags: jquery, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts

I am using js-hotkeys and when I press a hotkey like "f", it adds an f to the input field that I pulled up and focus on.

Is there anyway for it not to do that?

I also tried this other plugin http://rikrikrik.com/jquery/shortkeys/#download and it doesnt have that issue but then that plugin had other issue.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can prevent the default action using [`event.preventDefault()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/), in this case that default action is adding the letter to the textbox, for example:

```
$(document).bind('keydown', 'f', function(e) {
  $("input").focus();
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

<sub>*Note:* For those of you going WTF?: This is the syntax the plugin adds, it's not the normal [`.bind()`](http://api.jquery.com/bind/) jQuery core syntax.</sub>

I suggest you take a look at [John Resig's re-write of the jQuery hotkeys plugin here](http://github.com/jeresig/jquery.hotkeys), it's a much more efficient and 1.4.2+ compatible plugin, [you can find the readme here](http://github.com/jeresig/jquery.hotkeys/blob/master/README.md).

[See it in action here](http://www.jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/x4gJJ/).

Comment: ah brilliant yet again Nick. Actually I am using John's rewrite and it had the problem. But your suggestion fixed it. Seems like a bug on the plugin.